# In mysql, timestamp is not generating date. Why?

Tags: mysql, date

Column called “jdate” is defined as “varchar(19),
And before insert rows into the table called “fatable”

```
alter table fatable CHANGE jdate jdate TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
Then, inserting a row like:
insert into fatable (firstname,lastname, address, city, state, zip, phoneno, emailad, jdate, ddate, cstatus, investam, wamount, comments) 
values('john','lee','10 rustling lane','bedford','ny','10506','9142347752','support@poosung.com', '','09262015','0','100','10','aa');
```

---

The result:

```
# id, firstname, lastname, address, city, state, zip, phoneno, emailad, timestamp, ddate, cstatus, investam, wamount, comments
'2015101', 'john', 'lee', '10 rustling lane', 'bedford', 'ny', '10506', '9142347752', 'support@poosung.com', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '09262015', '0', '100.00', '10.00', 'aa'
```

---

The column “jdate” has mysql date format with all zeroes.    No current date shown.

Comment: You're inserting an empty string: `''`, try to insert instead: `now()`

Comment: The first timestamp column by default is zero, you are change `jdate` but trying to insert a value in `timestamp`, also you are not query that column in your select...

Comment: Also, if a column allows `NULL`, mysql uses an explicit `DEFAULT NULL` for the column, try changing the alter table to be `NOT NULL` instead of `NULL` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/data-type-defaults.html

Comment: @Aguardientico, thanks for your attention.   I tried NOT NULL and the result is the same.   The guideline is that NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP would generate the time as insert or update to the database is executed.   I even tried to use "MODIFY COLUMN"  to see if MySQL changes column spec, but it does not.  By the way, the testing platform is MySQL workbench.    NOW() is to generate the current date information as the row is updated, leaving the original creation date untouched, as I understand, unless I am wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In ref to 'ALTER TABLE my_table Change column_for_date column_for_date TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;' does not work(MySQL 5.6).  Instead, define LIKE "column_for_date 'TIMESTAMP DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',"
2. then, before insert, enter CREATE TRIGGER clause like "CREATE TRIGGER a_dummy_name BEFORE INSERT ON table_name FOR EACH ROW SET NEW. table_name=UTC_TIMESTAMP;'
3. where insert clauses are, values('NOT NULL','a_value_for_the_next column....on and on);
   I put the column for the date right behind ID.   I.E. as a 2nd column.
   Wishing everyone luck.

Answer (score 0):

We don't see a reference to the changed `jdate` column in the result. (There's a column named `timestamp` and column named `ddate`).

The MySQL Reference Manual covers this topic of automatic initialization of TIMESTAMP column fairly well.

Some possible causes for the behavior you are observing: timestamp column allows a NULL value, value for timestamp column supplied/assigned in INSERT, more than one timestamp column in the table, etc.

There's not enough information provided in the question to provide the exact answer.  The `ALTER TABLE` statement references column named **`jdate`**, but we don't see any reference to that column in the INSERT (which is what we'd expect if you want the value automatically initialized), but confusingly, the result doesn't show a column named `jdate`.

Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/timestamp-initialization.html

Comment: thanks for your attention.   I revised the row head called "timestamp'.  That was an error.   The test was done with the head, "jdate'.   While testing several options to find the solution, I was using "timestamp" as head label.   It did not work.

Comment: the first comment, had your name, but print shows none.   Sorry for that.  I read as you mention the initialization reference.   And, I could not find the solution from the guidelines the reference gave. On the matter of having more than one timestamp column, I have only one column in the table and naturally in each row with the label "jdate".